# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la versión predeterminada de gradle que otorga visual studio code a los nuevos proyectos de flutter?

Tags: flutter, vscode, gradle, build.gradle

trabajo con Visual Studio Code, al crear:

1- Flutter: New Proyect

2- Aplication

por defecto en las configuraciones para android salen de esta forma
algunos archivos:

Archivo "build.gradle":

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

y otro archivo llamado "gradle-wrapper.properties":

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

Como pueden observar la versión de gradle predeterminada es:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

y la versión del complemento de Android para Gradle es:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

que obviamente no son las últimas y me gustaría saber que tengo que modificar en mi Visual Studio Code para que al crear un nuevo proyecto lo haga automáticamente ya con las últimas versiones en estas líneas y así ahorrarme el tener que modificar estos ficheros cada vez que cree un proyecto nuevo.

Gracias